# Dynamic time scheduling advice

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I am using Jboss5.1.x, EJB3.0, Quartz 1.8

I have System which is being activated at specific time(surrounding that time).
The system should work once in a day.

I am setting value in a database which mention the activation time and every hour the system is pulling that value to check if the current time is matching the value (in case it is the system will activate  itself).
This time has to be changeable in the future dynamiclly.

Now this technic gives me a headache, since I need to do some Math calculations (in case the current time has passed in couple of mins I still need to activate the system.
more over I need to take care for a case the system already activated so it wont be activated again in the same day (due to a time mistake caluclations.)

I could think about other technic which pulling the database once in couple of days to check if the activiation time has ever change(in this case I wont need to pull every hour, but in other case i am not sure Quartz can re-schedualre it's triggers while it's running)

any ideas? solutions?

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Please check quartz framework..... quartz can do all. With the help of quartz you not need to manage database for this comparasion....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This a great example for my solution:

[Dynamic time scheduling advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990612/dynamic-time-scheduling-advice)

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can reschedule triggers while Quartz is running (or add new triggers).

You can even do that from within the executing jobs if you like.

Comment: Yes I have figured it already. I will past in my answer some piece of code.